# Adding rows to second column ONLY - populating data using a for loop

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, datagridview

I calculate the amount of rows I want to have in my **second** column using a for loop based on reading how many records a file has that has been opened. I have researched and tried various solutions but nothing works, yet it seems so simple. Below is my current code where I retrieve the file's length and do a quick sum, entering a for loop where (at the moment) I am only able to populate the first column.

```
long Count = 1;
FileInfo Fi = new FileInfo(file);
long sum = (Fi.Length / 1024) - Count;

for (int i = 0; i < sum; i++)
{
    DataGridView1.Rows.Add(Count++);
}
```

I'm not sure how to do it but I know the above code adds to the first column by default - I don't know how to modify it. I know by:

```
DataGridView1.Rows.Add("a","b");
```

... The 'b' value is displayed in the second column, but I don't want anything for now in the first where 'a' is.

I have looked at [insert a row with one column datagridview c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6743044/insert-a-row-with-one-column-datagridview-c-sharp) but it is related to merging columns, again, I don't want this.

```
DataGridView1.Rows.Add("",Count++);
```

Works to an extent, but is not the right way to do it. I'm going to be adding data to the first column later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to omit the value for the first column, just add `null` or [`DBNull.Value`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.dbnull.value%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), e.g.:

```
DataGridView1.Rows.Add(DBNull.Value, Count++);
```

This way, the first column will be empty while the second columns contains the value of `Count`.