# "Get #1, 1, Data" (VB) in C#?

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio

*Please note, some code has been used in another question but for other reasons. This is at:* [Adding rows to second column ONLY - populating data using a for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21404668/adding-rows-to-second-column-only-populating-data-using-a-for-loop)

---

Currently, I am able to calculate the amount of rows required in my DataGridView from reading a .bin file using the following code:

```
long Count = 1;
FileInfo Fi = new FileInfo(import.FileName);
long sum = (Fi.Length / 1024) - Count;

for (int i = 0; i < sum; i++)
{
    DataGridView1.Rows.Add(null, Count++);
}
```

My question is, I know in VB you can use, for example,

```
Get #1, 1, Data
```

... Which tells me to get Record 1 and I'm just wondering if there is a way to do this particular line in C#? I can't seem to find any kind of solution online.

Comment: My VB is a bit rusty, but I'm pretty sure that's not valid VB code you provided.

Comment: @Servy: This is legacy syntax from VB6.

Comment: That's like hybrid C# and VB :) Which really doesn't exist.

Comment: @SLaks Really? I stand corrected :)

Comment: @SLaks How is the token `#1` even going to compile?  That's not a valid literal or identifier to my understanding.

Comment: Are you just trying to get the row at a specific position?  Or a value in a column in a row?

Comment: @Servy: It's special syntax for file IO.  (just like VB6 had special syntax for `Print`) This is one of the reasons I hate VB.

Comment: @SLaks: This is not supported in VB.NET at all.

Comment: I haven't had much experience with VB, but I got the above "Get #1, 1, Data" from http://www.vbi.org/Items/article.asp?id=16. I was just researching about Random Access Files in VB and I have seen the outline of this code used in an application - obviously not word-by-word but very similar. @EvanL from a specific position I think, I'm just wondering what the best way to go about it is.

Comment: @Servy that goes back to 8088 Basica days - it is a literal file token, but as far back as QB there was support to get a handle as a variable - FreeFile.

Comment: The 'Get' file syntax is supported only up to VB6.  There are more coherent ways to do this in VB.NET.

Comment: @lornasw: Unless you're upgrading legacy code and need to maintain compatibility, you should not even think about this.  Instead, use JSON or XML.

Comment: You also need to know how the file was opened. There are two possibilities: Random and Binary access. The command will be something like `FILE OPEN _filename_ FOR RANDOM AS #1`. Random access and Binary get data in different ways, even from the same file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to maintain legacy formats from VB6, you can call the .Net methods that this syntax compiles to directly:

```
FileSystem.FileGet(1, ref Data, 1);
```

For more information, see the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.filesystem)